# Quick question about SMD diodes

Tags: diodes, surface-mount

I need help identifying an smd diode (see picture)
It appears to have 5423 written on it, but I can't find anywhere a diode by this code. I did however find an smd diode by googling 5243 (I figured that it I might have to read it vertically, not horizontally). 
Also, 1 of these reads 0.1 when tested with multimeter and another reads 0.2. I have desoldered them both to be 100% sure and the result remained the same. Does that mean the one with 0.1 voltage drop is the bad one? I also tried switching multimeter leads, both read OL as expected. Also, I measured resistance: the one with 0.1 voltage drop read 200-300 ohms, whereas the other one was OL (that's while probing using the correct polarity). After switching multimeter leads it read OL resistance for both diodes.
Thank you in advance!

[image: smdO diode]

Comment: `"It appears to have 5423 written on it"` - I read 5324.

Comment: Sorry, it was a photo of the wrong diode, so it solves the different reading I guess ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's RSX201L-30 Schottky diode (30V/2A). Datasheet: http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/diode/schottky_barrier/rsx201l-30.pdf